# Rails 4, asset pipeline causes user downloadable files to be downloaded twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sendfile

I have a folder in my app directory named "uploads" where users can upload files and download files.  I don't want the uploads folder to be in the public directory because I want to control download authorization.

In my controller, I have:

```
send_file Rails.root.join('app', 'uploads', filename), :type => 'application/zip', :disposition => 'inline', :x_sendfile=>true
```

This actually works fine.  The problem is that when I'm on the production server, when I run the rake assets:precompile, and have an assets directory, the file downloads twice.  The first time the file downloads, the browser acts as if nothing is going on (no loading spinning), but I see data being transferred in the Google Chrome web developer Network tab.  Then after the file has been downloaded, a prompt comes up asking the user if he/she wants to download the file.

Removing the assets folder in the public directory gets rid of this problem, but I want to use the asset pipeline.  I also tried changing the asset pipeline requires from require_tree to require_directory.

Does anyone know how to get send_file working properly with the asset pipeline?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like it's Turbolinks that is causing this problem.  I can see that this function in javascript is being called:    `visit = function(url) {
    if (browserSupportsPushState && browserIsntBuggy) {
      cacheCurrentPage();
      reflectNewUrl(url);
      return fetchReplacement(url);
    } else {
      return document.location.href = url;
    }
  };`  which causes the file to be downloaded twice.  Now the question is... how can I disable turbolinks for one method?

Comment: For anyone having this problem, I solved it.  Pass `'data-no-turbolink' => true` into the link_to helper to stop Turbolinks from messing with the download.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone having this problem, I solved it. Pass

```
'data-no-turbolink' => true
```

into the link_to helper to stop Turbolinks from messing with the download.

https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/182

Comment: Changed to `'data-turbolinks' => false`.

Answer (score 0):

But if you are using a form with `turbooboost = true`, instead of link_to, or even with a link_to you can do it like this:

Inside your **controller**, and inside your **action** put:

```
def download
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
          data = "Hello World!"
          filename = "Your_filename.docx"
          send_data(data, type: 'application/docx', filename: filename)
        end
        format.js { render js: "window.location.href = '#{controller_download_path(params)}';" }
      end
  end
```

Replace `controller_download_path` with a path to your `download` action,

and place in your **routes** both `post` and `get` for the same path:

```
post '/download'  => 'your_controller#download',  as: :controller_download
get '/download'  => 'your_controller#download',  as: :controller_download
```