# Ruby on Rails send_file doesn't work until i refresh the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delay, sendfile

I am working on a Rails server which I can download my locally stored movies and anime etc from. This is kind of working but when I click the download link I have to refresh the page in order for the download to actually start.

This is the controller that handles the download:

```
class DownloadController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @title = params[:title]
    @name = params[:name]
    @path = '/media/sf_Anime,_VN,_LN/Watching, not watched yet/'+@title+'/'+@name
    send_file( @path )
  end
end
```

and this is the link that links to that controller:

```
<% @episodes.each do |x| %>
<p> <%= x %><%= link_to " Download", 
    {controller: 'download', action: 'index', title: @title, name: x } %> </p>
<% end %>
```

**edit:**
I did some testing today and noticed that the download links work instantly if i try to send a smaller file (text or image). I also noticed that the download links actually works for the movies aswell but it takes 20-30 seconds for the download to start.
Do you have any idea of what would cause this delay?

Answer (score 4):

Are you using turbolinks?  Turbolinks apparently doesn't play nicely with send_file (https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/182). Try adding "data: { no-turbolink: true }" (or "'data-no-turbolink'=>true") in the link_to helper, e.g.:

```
<%= link_to "Downloadable File", downloadable_file, data: { no-turbolink: true } %>
```

See also: [Rails 4, asset pipeline causes user downloadable files to be downloaded twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506841/rails-4-asset-pipeline-causes-user-downloadable-files-to-be-downloaded-twice), [rails won't send_data as file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818015/rails-wont-send-data-as-file), [Ruby on Rails send_file, code in controller action running twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144584/ruby-on-rails-send-file-code-in-controller-action-running-twice)

Comment: I had to write it : <%= link_to... data: { :"no-turbolinks" => true } %> to make it work. Looks like ruby don't like dashed symbols.

Comment: I had both `data: {remote: true, :'no-turbolinks' => true}` so removing `remote: true` fixed the issue

Comment: I wish I could buy you a beer

Answer (score 0):

Edited to reflect comment below. I would simple add a concern for handling downloads and then use

```
include Concerns::Downloads
```

to handle your download request. the routes.rb would look like this.

```
resources :movies do
member do
  post 'download'
end
```

and in the view

```
  <%= link_to 'Download', {:controller => 'movies', :action => 'download'}, {:method => :post } %></a>
```

Comment: I tried moving the send_file section into a method, that didn't change anything though :/ but thanks!

Comment: @user3551655 Having looked further I would not have a Downloads controller, but instead create a concern within your movies controller which handles the downloading of your movies.

Comment: updated my post with some tests i did today. Sorry about not responding earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Move the file to public folder
add only file name into link_to

```
<%= link_to "Downloadable File", "/"+filename, %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the disposition to attachment in `send_file`:

```
class DownloadController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ...
    send_file( @path, :disposition => 'attachment' )
  end
end
```

The issue may be that your browser is trying to open the file itself - `:disposition => 'attachment'` prompts the browser to download the file, even if it thinks the file is something that it can open.

Comment: updated my post with some tests i did today. Sorry about not responding earlier.

Comment: `'attachment'` is the default option for `send_file`.