# Ruby send_file doesn't work unless link is loaded on new tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For whatever reason, my `send_file` doesn't actually prompt the user to download the file. However, If I right click on the link that triggers the `send_file` action, then the user is prompted to download the file. It just doesn't prompt it on the same page as the link.

Not sure why this is happening, but here's my action in the controller:

```
  # GET /consultants/agents/1/download_ssh_key
  def download_ssh_key
    @agent = Agent.find(params[:agent_id])
    send_file "/home/shared/agent_#{@agent.uuid}"
  end
```

When I click this link in the browser (without opening a new tab), this is what I see in the console:

```
I, [2019-10-05T22:40:47.713625 #3211]  INFO -- : [1f170528-920b-4330-9d17-7107220235dd] Started GET "/consultants/agents/9/download_ssh_key" for 66.195.29.70 at 2019-10-05 22:40:47 -0500
I, [2019-10-05T22:40:47.714597 #3211]  INFO -- : [1f170528-920b-4330-9d17-7107220235dd] Processing by Consultants::AgentsController#download_ssh_key as HTML
I, [2019-10-05T22:40:47.714673 #3211]  INFO -- : [1f170528-920b-4330-9d17-7107220235dd]   Parameters: {"agent_id"=>"9"}
D, [2019-10-05T22:40:47.717697 #3211] DEBUG -- : [1f170528-920b-4330-9d17-7107220235dd]   Agent Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `agents`.* FROM `agents` WHERE `agents`.`id` = 9 LIMIT 1
I, [2019-10-05T22:40:47.719397 #3211]  INFO -- : [1f170528-920b-4330-9d17-7107220235dd] Sent file /home/shared/agent_22ac92d1 (0.3ms)
I, [2019-10-05T22:40:47.720488 #3211]  INFO -- : [1f170528-920b-4330-9d17-7107220235dd] Completed 200 OK in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Am I missing something in my `send_file` action that is supposed to trigger a download prompt? According to https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file, the default option is to send it as an attachment (prompt for download) rather than loading the file in the browser.

Comment: Does it help if you specify an http content type?
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file

Comment: From the logs, it looks like rails is doing the right thing and the browser is not. Does that happen on any browser? what happen if the file has an extension? Do you see any warning o error on the browser's console or network tab on dev tools?

Comment: @arieljuod No errors or warnings in the console and the network tab just shows a 200 with the content within the HTTP response. The file that it is sending back also has an extension too with no luck.

Comment: Are you using Turbolink? If yes, can you try to disable it as mentioned 
 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25826223/2245697